# H2 UDF Classpath

Tags: java, database, classpath, h2, user-defined-functions

When I create an ALIAS for registering the java function in the H2 database, it gives error of class not found.

I try to use the basic Function isPrime from the Documentation

```
package acme;
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class Function {
    public static boolean isPrime(int value) {
        return new BigInteger(String.valueOf(value)).isProbablePrime(100);
    }
}
```

I know the requirements for this (public, static and classpath)

I create an Classpath Entry for this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\src\test\org\h2\acme
```

ERROR: Klasse "acme.Function" nicht gefunden Code: 90086

But it doesn't Work... Can someone give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it should be 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\H2\src\test` on the `classpath`.

and `package org.h2.acme` inside Java file.

Comment: I changed it that way, but it still doesn't work.
My Registrate Command is: CREATE ALIAS IS_PRIME FOR "acme.Function.isPrime";